# How to put a sectlof outside its section

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I would like to put section-based list of figures out of their sections and in an appendix, but for only for two specific sections. 
My intention was to put the sectlof, like it would appear in section 2 and appendix B, instead in appendix C. I only need a list of figures for these two sections, the rest is not needed.

My problem is that I did not manage to put a sectlof outside its section. Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[insection]{minitoc}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}


\begin{document}

  \dosectlof 
  \fakelistoffigures

  \section{Section 1}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

  \section{Section 2}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \caption{some figure}
  \end{figure}

  \sectlof

  \begin{appendices}

    \section{Appendix A}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

    \section{Appendix B}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

    \begin{figure}[htb]
      \caption{another figure}
    \end{figure}

    \sectlof

    \section{Appendix C}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

    Figures of section 2
    %I want to put the sectlof of section 2 here

    Figures of appendix B
    %I want to put the sectlof of appendix B here

  \end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). is it possible to post your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Would it be an option for you to use `titletoc` instead of `minitoc` (I am not familiar with the latter)?

Comment: Also, please describe in more detail your intent; your current description is confusing (at least for me). In appendix C you want to print a partial list of figures that must include figures that appear where exactly?

Comment: If titletoc does the job it would be great, I hope my question is now more clear

Comment: @SpinNE555 yes, your question is now clear. Thanks for clarifying. Please see my answer for a solution using `titletoc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the constraint to use `minitoc` has been lifted in a comment to the question, I provide a solution using  [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) (perhaps there's also an easy solution with `minitoc`, but I am not familiar with this package): the idea is to use

```
\startlist[<name>]{lof}
```

where each partial list should begin, and

```
\stoplist[<name>]{lof}
```

where each list should end. Then, you can use

```
\printlist[<name>]{lof}{}{<formatting commands>}
```

to print the list on the desired location (of course, use a different `<name>` for each partial list). A complete example (I used some \clearpage commands just for the example, but they can be safely deleted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{some figure on section 1}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\section{Section 2}
\startlist[a]{lof}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{some figure on section 2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{some other figure on section 2}
\end{figure}
\stoplist[a]{lof}
\clearpage

\begin{appendices}

\section{Appendix A}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{some figure on appendix A}
\end{figure}
\clearpage

\section{Appendix B}
\startlist[b]{lof}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{some figure in appendix B}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{Another figure in appendix B}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{Yet another figure in appendix B}
\end{figure}

\stoplist[b]{lof}
\clearpage

\section{Appendix C}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

\printlist[a]{lof}{}{\subsection*{List of Figures for Section 2}}

\printlist[b]{lof}{}{\subsection*{List of Figures for Appendix B}}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

An image of Appendix C showing both partial LoFS:

[image]